# CSV filename in date-form as Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a couple of csv files that have as title yyyymmdd: [image: 'yyyymmdd']. I also have a several csv files that have 'yyyymm' and one with 'yyyy' which I **don't** want to import.

Problem is, the csv files themselves only have time and not date:

[image: datetimeformat].

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

photolist = glob('********.csv')

dataframes = [pd.read_csv(Tage, delimiter=';',
                    skiprows=2,
                    encoding='cp1252',
                    parse_dates = True,
                    index_col = 0) for Tage in photolist]


print(dataframes)
```

The index for the dataframes returns the right time but not the right date.

So my question is: How can I have the same date as index as the csv filname?

Comment: Like you wrote the csv does not contain any date... but the parser adds the actual date to parsed times so it is a datetime format... you could just add the date from the filename after reading each dataframe.

Comment: @ Drise Thank you for noticing, I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the date that is the filename instead of the date automatically defined by pandas.

Here how to do that:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

photolist = glob('*.csv')
def load_dataframe(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=';',
                    skiprows=2,
                    encoding='cp1252',
                    parse_dates = True,
                    index_col = 0)

    df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(
             path.split(".")[0] +" " + df.index.to_series().dt.time.astype(str)))
    return df 

dataframes = [load_dataframe(Tage) for Tage in photolist]
```

---

### Explanation:

Compared to your solution, the only thing that is different is the following:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(
             path.split(".")[0] +" " + df.index.to_series().dt.time.astype(str)))
```

Let's explain it with an example:

Given a dataframe df, that has a datetime index:

```
                     column
2017-08-12 08:00:00       1
2017-08-12 09:15:12       2
2017-08-12 10:45:23       3
```

We can change the date from `2017-08-12` to `2019-10-11` as follows:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(
    "20191011" + " "+ df.index.to_series().dt.time.astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
                     column
2019-10-11 08:00:00       1
2019-10-11 09:15:12       2
2019-10-11 10:45:23       3
```

---

### Edit: answer to the OP's error

The error message is pointing to the issue `ValueError: month must be in 1..12`.

So, either `pd.to_datetime` is not able to infer the right date format or you have erroneous dates in your data. Assuming your data is correct, here's how you can specify explicitly the date format:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(
             path.split(".")[0] +" " + df.index.to_series().dt.time.astype(str),
             format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

---

### Edit 2:

Answer to the question in the comments below:

> Any idea how to make the code run without having to delete the yyyymm and yyyy files?

You can use list Comprehension as follows:

```
photolist = glob('*.csv')
photolist = [i for i in photolist if len(i) == 12]
```

Comment: @TimB, please remove the answer that you posted as it's against the guidelines of stackoverflow. I encourage you to edit your question and add the new error in the bottom.

Comment: @TimB can you share the versions of pandas and python ?

Comment: Sure, I am using Python 3.6.4 and Pandas 0.22

Comment: Thank you, I think I spotted the mistake. I did not mention that in the folder there also are 12 yyyymm files and 1 yyyy file. If I delete these files there is no error, however if I returne the dataframes I get 'None' . Why is that? I edited my post to make it better understandable.

Comment: @TimB. make sure that you copy the complete function with the `return df`

Comment: Okay code works now. Any idea how to make the code run without having to delete the yyyymm and yyyy files?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Code works now, I'm new to stackoverflow. I also upvoted your response